# can select multiple be draggable?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var drag = document.getElementById("drag");

drag.onclick = function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
#drag {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<select id="drag" multiple="">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

is it possible with javascript to stop the hold-select effect and make it a drag to change elements order in the list?

i tried to `e.preventDefault()` and to bind a `draggable script` in options but did not work

Comment: There's a JS library  out of the box to create sortable lists and grids using native HTML5 see https://github.com/lukasoppermann/html5sortable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with select element :

Trying to change the code you provide making a simple [one](https://jsfiddle.net/rxsb96k2/)

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

**script.js :**

```
$("ul").on('click', 'li', function (e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass('selected');
    }
}).sortable({
    connectWith: "ul",
    delay: 150, 
    revert: 0,

});
```

However you can use [multiselect](https://github.com/michael/multiselect) plugin  ,a demo [here](http://www.quasipartikel.at/multiselect/)

**EDITED :**

If you still want the select tag look you can use [dragOptions](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Sorting-Select-Options-With-Drag-Drop-jQuery-dragOptions.html)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#drag").dragOptions({
        onDrag: function(){
            console.log('onDrag callback: ', this);
        },
        onChange: function(){
            console.log('onChange callback: ', this);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>drag</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="form-group">
    <select id="drag" size="5" class="form-control">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://gitcdn.link/repo/NikitaKA/jquery.dragOptions/master/jquery.dragoptions.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
</html>
```

As you  see when you drag an option an error occurs (maybe an issue))

If someone can tell me what's going wrong here i will appreciate that !

Hope that helps someone .

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<html>
    <script>
    var _el;
    
    function dragOver(e) {
      if (isBefore(_el, e.target))
        e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(_el, e.target);
      else
        e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(_el, e.target.nextSibling);
    }
    
    function dragStart(e) {
      e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
      e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", null); // Thanks to bqlou for their comment.
      _el = e.target;
    }
    
    function isBefore(el1, el2) {
      if (el2.parentNode === el1.parentNode)
        for (var cur = el1.previousSibling; cur && cur.nodeType !== 9; cur = cur.previousSibling)
          if (cur === el2)
            return true;
      return false;
    }
    </script>
    <select name="draglist" multiple>
      <option draggable="true" ondragover="dragOver(event)" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" value="1">Apples</option>
      <option draggable="true" ondragover="dragOver(event)" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" value="2">Oranges</option>
      <option draggable="true" ondragover="dragOver(event)" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" value="3">Bananas</option>
      <option draggable="true" ondragover="dragOver(event)" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" value="4">Strawberries</option>
    </select>
    </html>
```

Comment: how did this work for you?  I tried the same, on a `<select multiple>` and it does not work.  When I highlight one `option` and try to drag it up or down, the other options above it (or down from it) just highlight as if I am trying to highlight multiple options at once.